# 'Unable to get value from JSON object in node js

Tags: json, node.js

I have a jsp file that returns a json object using the following code:

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

    object.put("name","domain");
    object.put("email","domain.com");

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(object.toString());
```

The output is: {"name":"domain","email":"domain.com"}

I trying to get the values from this JSON using following code in node.js:

```
        var endpoint = // contains the address of the above jsp file;

        var body = ""
        http.get(endpoint, (response) => {
          response.on('data', (chunk) => { body += chunk })
          response.on('end', () => {
            console.log("Body: "+body);
            console.log("Body name: "+body.name);
          })
        })
```

In the above snippet I get following output for console.log -

Body: {"name":"domain","email":"domain.com"}

Body name: undefined

I don't know why "body.name" is not working.
Could any body please help in getting the values from the json object. Since, body itself is json object so I don't need to do JSON.parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You have to parse the JSON string to assign it to a js object.

```
    var endpoint = // contains the address of the above jsp file;

    var body = {}
    http.get(endpoint, (response) => {
      response.on('data', (chunk) => { body = JSON.parse(chunk) })
      response.on('end', () => {
        console.log("Body: "+body);
        console.log("Body name: "+body.name);
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

`body` object is string. Because of that when you try to write it in console:

```
console.log("Body: "+body);
```

You get this:

```
Body: {"name":"domain","email":"domain.com"}
```

But since body is string you cannot get its property `name`. String doesn't have proerty `name`. You should firstly [parse string to JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
    var endpoint = // contains the address of the above jsp file;

    var body = ""
    http.get(endpoint, (response) => {
      response.on('data', (chunk) => { body += chunk })
      response.on('end', () => {
        console.log("Body: "+ body);
        var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Body name: "+ parsedBody .name);
      })
    })
```